# Work out value between two numbers from percentage.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example I have a minimum number `200`, a maximum number `680`, and a percentage between 0% and 100%. How do I work out the value between 200 and 680 when the percentage is 30% (or any other between 0 and 100)?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything and thanks in advance.

Comment: 10% of 680 is 68. 30% of 680 would be...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take $x=680-200=480$ and then you find the percentage of $x$, you will have your answer by adding $200$ to previous result.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! I can accept the answer in a few minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$y=\frac { 480 }{ 100 } p+200$$

For $p=30 $ you have $y=\frac { 480 }{ 100 } 30+200 = 344$

Answer (score 3):

Well another way to look about it could be you find difference between maximum value and minimum value which is rightly calculated as 480 in first question. Then you can divide 480 in 100 equal parts of size 4.8.
Now if you have to find 30% you simply find it as:

 200+4.8*30 = 344.

If you ever need more help in such questions you can count on algebrahomeworkhelp.info
Once they really saved me from being expelled.